# Regular expression to match 1 through 12 with padding?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to match any of the following: `01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12`

Normally I would just do `[1-12]` but I need the padding of the zero if it is only one digit. Having a bit of a brainfart on how to do that elegantly.

Comment: Is something like `[0-1][0-9]` okay?

Comment: @rendon: Wouldn't that match 13-19 as well?

Comment: `[1-12]` only matches character digits `1` or `2`, it matches nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex.

```
^0[1-9]|1[012]$
```

Comment: Ah okay I was afraid it'd have to be something like that. Okay thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With some nice capturing matching fun:

```
/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/
```